# Using Team Explorer to add an existing project Team Foundation Service

Tags: c#, version-control, azure-devops, team-explorer

I'm just getting into Team Foundation "Service", this in turn is my first exposure to Team Foundation Server.

Im a bit muddled about a couple of things. I have existing C# solutions, some comprising 30 C# projects. I want to put them under the version control of TFS. So a couple of questions:

1. Does version control only "apply" at the c# solution level. I dont seem to be able to add an individual    project to TFS, only a solution.
2. Do all C# projects need to sit beneath the C# solution in an NTFS directory hierarchy? I cant seem to add a c# project to an online TFS collection unless that C# project has the C# solution folder as its root. 
   This is not always the case for me since I use solutions as "views" depending upon the aspect of the application I am developing. 
   So do I need to change my local layout to work with TFS and version control or can I somehow link projects from disparate local location to a single TFS repository?
3. All my Team Explorer Connect icons always appear in black?

[image: Team Explorer Connect Black icons]

And yet all the documentation and other posts I see on the net plus here ion SO have red/orange icons.

[image: Team Explorer Connect Red/Orange icons]

Do this mean I'm disconnected or something else? Also, I don't get the "Publish" option in the context menu. Instead I have to do what feels like the long way round buy doing a local commit then go changes/commit/push.